# PrimOps in GHCi

Tags: ghci

Is it possible to use PrimOps in GHCi? The following does not work:

```
$ ghci -XMagicHash
GHCi, version 8.10.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/stefan/.ghci
λ> let x = 42.0# :: Float#

<interactive>:1:18: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Float#’
    Perhaps you meant ‘Float’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Importing `Prelude` manually does not solve this error.

**Update:** After importing `GHC.Exts` the following error shows up:

```
$ ghci -XMagicHash
GHCi, version 8.10.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/stefan/.ghci
λ> import GHC.Exts
λ> let x = 42.0# :: Float#

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    GHCi can't bind a variable of unlifted type: x :: Float#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MagicHash` extension just makes it legal to use `#` in names. If you want to specify types like `Float#`, you still need to import them. Do `import GHC.Exts` and try again.

Also, you can't bind them with `let`. You need to immediately use them and rewrap them.

Comment: After importing `GHC.Exts` another error shows up. I updated my initial question to reflect this.